# what is the value of Arg1 and Arg2 on onItemClick?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm trying to change one TextView in any view in my ListView,

And I already got one Adapter set so I can't use adapters for this.

I tried to do it in a "for" statement, using

```
mListView.getChildAt(i)
```

but it didn't worked.

when I tried to do it inside the OnItemClick method, using `arg1` instead of

`mListView.getChildAt(i)`, it worked for the item I clicked.

But i need it to happen without clicking on an item,

So my question is: What is the value of `Arg1` and `Arg2`?

I know what they represent, but I want to know what value do they get when I click on an item.

Thanks.

Comment: does it mean you don't have adapter for your list view? if you have, you implement getItem inside your adapter. like : `@Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
   return itemList.get(position);
 }`

Comment: `getItem()` returns String, not View.

Comment: nope.It returns what you have in your list. i.e. itemList in above example code.

Comment: my adapter is ArrayAdapter set with values inside the brackets. it returns String when I ask for getItem. I need it to get view, how do I do it?

Comment: I think you should add all relevant codes in your question so that SO user understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: I would suggest you to create custom adapter instead of using ArrayAdapter which extends base adapter. and override methods : getItem(), getView(),getItemId(), and getCount(). It will make your life easy for sure.

Comment: I'm using ArrayAdapter to match a list to TextView in any view, which is basically what I'm trying to do without adapter.

Comment: So, lets take it the other way. Is there A way that I could set more than one adapter to a single listview?

Comment: I am not aware of that scenario. But you can customize your one adapter for almost all your needs for one type of list view contents.

Comment: "I'm using ArrayAdapter to match a list to TextView in any view, which is basically what I'm trying to do without adapter." Is there A way to match multiple lists to multiple TextViews in one ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

you can fake a click through `view.performClick()` method if that is what you need

Comment: `mListView.getChildAt(6).performClick();` for example, gives NullPointerException.

Comment: that is because android will recycle through your list view please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Answer (score 0):

From Android documentation :

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

**Parameters :**

**parent**  The AdapterView where the click happened.

**view**    The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

**position**    The position of the view in the adapter.

**id**  The row id of the item that was clicked.

Comment: I need Arg1 value. how can I get Arg1 value (View) using getItemAtPosition? I couldn't find a way. I get it that this method gets the View and Position, but how? what is the value they get set to?

Comment: @user3184899 It's a callback event. It is called whenever the view is touched. You just can't simple get the value by using `getItemAtPosition()`

Comment: let me ask it different. how can I get an Array of all of my ListView views?